# Ввод-вывод в файл

Tags: c++, c++builder

Есть txt файл "semiya.txt", в котором есть список:

```
мама
папа
брат
сестра
```

(в столбике). Надо создать другой txt файл "ishod.txt", который выглядел бы так:

```
0="мама",
1="папа",
2="брат",
3="сестра",
```

(после запятой начинается новая строка, т.е. так же в столбике).

Подскажите, как это реализовать в C++!

Answer (score 4):

В таком духе:

```
string line;
ifstream source ("from.txt");

int i = 0;

if (source.is_open()) {
    while (source.good()) {
        getline(source, line);
        cout << i++ << "=\""  << line << "\"" << endl;
    }
    source.close();
}
```

Вывод в файл вам в качестве упражнения.

Answer (score 2):

Открываем файл semiya.txt на чтение,

```
FILE *semia = fopen("semia.txt","r");
```

а файл ishod.txt на запись,

```
FILE *ishod = fopen("ishod.txt","w");
```

и устанавливаем счечик строк.

```
int k = 0;
```

Читаем построчно (но в случае с Вашим форматом файла удобнее *пословно*)

```
char w[100];
while (fscanf(semia,"%s",w) == 1)
```

semia.txt . По прочтении строки (слова) формируем строку файла ishod.txt и увеличиваем счетчик.

Что-то вроде:

```
fprintf (ishod,"%d=\"%s\",\n",k++,w);
```

Собственно все. С Новым Годом !