# Чтение файла посимвольно. Парсинг массива символов как строки с условием С++

Tags: c++, c, строки, char

Задача:
Читать файл построчно, строка заносится в символьный буфер.
Посимвольно каждый символ сравнивается с "правильными" (I,J), после символа идет число, которое пишется в переменную делится на 1000 и выводится на экран.
Мусорные символы: F,R,H,Q и прочий шлак пропускается.

Пытался накодить, получилось вывести только цифры из первой строки много-много раз, а дальше никак =(
Долблюсь головой об стол. Не понимаю что не так. 
Подскажите пожалуйста кому интересно =)

**Пример входного файла.**

В нем рандомно встречаются разные буквы и цифры вразброс.

---

`N10I-255961J-829096F-360873
N11I-254238F-360873
N12J931921
N13Y-251413H-332067
N14I-653588
N15I248588F-332245
N16Q251413J-332085H-332067
N17I252145J331921
.....................
.....................
.....................
 и так далее.........
 и так далее.........`

---

**Мой код.**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int k=0;
FILE *ifs = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
std::stringstream i,j;
float i1=0,j1=0;
char buf[1024];
while(fgets(buf,1024,ifs)){
while(buf[k]){
if (isalpha(buf[k])){
    if ((int)buf[k]==73 && ((int)buf[k+1] > 44 && (int)buf[k+1] < 58)){//I
    do {i<<buf[k+1];
    k++;}
        while (!isalpha(buf[k+1]));
        i>>i1;
        }

    if ((int)buf[k]==74 && ((int)buf[k+1] > 44 && (int)buf[k+1] < 58)){//J
    do {j<<buf[k+1];
    k++;}
        while (!isalpha(buf[k+1]));
        j>>j1;

    }
} else if (isdigit(buf[k])){
}
k++;}
std::cout <<"i" <<i1/1000<<std::endl;
std::cout <<"j" <<i1/1000<<std::endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

**Должно выводится на экран**

```
i-255.961
j-829.096
j931.921
i-653.588
i248.588
i252.145
j331.921
```

Comment: 1) проверьте исходник. Там явно ошибка в одной из фигурных скобок, не собирается. 2) Определитесь, `C` или `C++`. 3) Точней сформулируйте задачу: вывести число, которое следует сразу за символами `I` или `J`, остальное пропускать. Знак учитывается. Так?

Comment: @PinkTux спасибо что по правили. 1 Исходник проверил, теперь должен билдится. Пишу на плюсах (`c++`). 3 Да вывести число за символами `I` и `J`, остальное пропускать. Выше есть пример как это должно выглядеть. Знак учитывается. =)

Comment: @PinkTux при написании программы на `c++` можно использовать язык `c`,  но не наоборот, поставьте если ошибаюсь =)

Comment: Просто средства у них разные. Если это часть проекта на C++, или учебное задание на плюсах - имеет смысл использовать плюсовые средства. Если цель просто распарсить файл, то хоть на `awk` пишите... Но код в ответе соберётся как угодно, и чисто сишным, и плюсовым компилятором.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ввод-вывод в файл на C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66938/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На `C` (с учётом уточнений в вопросе):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char c;
    long n;
    FILE *in = fopen( "in.txt", "r" );

    if( !in ) {
        perror( "Can not open file" );
        return -1;
    }

    while( fscanf( in, "%c%ld", &c, &n ) != EOF ) {
        if( strchr( "iIjJ", c ) ) {
            printf( "%c%.3f\n", ( c | 0x20 ), ( double )n / 1000.0 );
        }
    }
    fclose( in );
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
i-255.961
j-829.096
i-254.238
j931.921
i-653.588
i248.588
j-332.085
i252.145
j331.921
```